# Why is String::IsNullOrEmpty() returning false in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli

I have the following C++/CLI code:

```
String^ str = gcnew String("", 0, 10);
bool isEmpty = String::IsNullOrEmpty(str);
```

Why is `String::IsNullOrEmpty()` is returning false?

Comment: Matt is right. Try IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) instead if you want to check the content of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131423(v=vs.110).aspx) (incorrectly):

```
public String(
    char* value,
    int startIndex,
    int length 
)
```

where

```
length 
    Type: System.Int32 
    The number of characters within value to use.
```

So, the length of your string is 10, and therefore, not empty.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was expecting the constructor to trim the input string up to *length*, not create a longer string if the input string is shorter than *length*.

Comment: @Ionian316 In this case, `char*` refers to a byte array of encoded characters in the thread's current default character set encoding; nothing else.

Comment: This also mean your call to the constructor is Undefined Behavior, because you make it read past the end of the string literal, where nasal demons could be lurking.